# Nginx does not work after configuring a load balancer

Tags: tomcat, nginx, load-balancing

I have been trying to configure a load balancer for two tomcat servers using nginx. To begin, I started my project on two different tomcat servers on differnet ports ( 8080 and 8081) and it worked.
Then, I downloaded nginx on windows 10, started it and I got the "welcome to nginx page" on localhost: 80.

Then I added some modificcations on the nginx conf file in order to configure the load balancer

```
 upstream new_servers {
            least_conn;
            server 127.0.0.1:8081;
            server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

and in location

```
location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://new_servers;
        }
```

I tried to do an " nginx -s reload" I stoped nginx and restarted it, but nothing seems to work I got always the

> 400 http error

here is all the conf file

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

 error_log  logs/error.log debug;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    debug_connection 127.0.0.1;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
     upstream new_servers {
            least_conn;
            server 127.0.0.1:8081;
            server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://new_servers;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

and nothing appears on the logs.

My questions are: 
What possibly created this error?

And once nginx will work? would it redirect me to one of the servers?

I have been working on this issue for two days, so i woul really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the nginx default port solved the issue.

And to answer the questions, yes nginx does redirect me to one of the servers.

If you want to see to what server we are redirected only add

```
log_format main 'to: $upstream_addr : $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

And go to the acces file to see the which server we are redirected " 
to "